# How to allow a user to use journalctl to see user-specific systemd service logs?

Tags: permissions, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, systemctl, journalctl

I am running user-level services in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  For example, I have my test.service located at `~/.config/systemd/user/test.service`.

I was able to run the service by doing

```
systemctl --user start test.target
```

However, when I try to read its log using `journalctl`, I got this error message:

```
journalctl --user -u test.service
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
  Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
  turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

How can I use `journalctl` for user's specific unit?

Comment: FTR, I'm not sure if it's the same situation, but what helped for me is adding the user to `systemd-journal` group with `sudo usermod -aG systemd-journal user` and then logging out/log in.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On older systemd versions, you'll have to use `journalctl --user --user-unit=SERVICENAME` (on newer versions `journalctl --user -u SERVICENAME` will work fine).

However, this only works if the `Storage` directive of the `[Journal]` section of `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` is set to `persistent` (instead of `auto` or `volatile`). Reboot after editing the configuration file and the user will be able to see the journal.

More information:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-October/037554.html

Comment: Adding the user to the systemd-journal group was the answer I needed (from that mailing list link).

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 17.10, where one user inexplicably couldn't view his logs, while another could.

Comment: Adding a user to the systemd-journal group would be a workaround, but since my service was a user service, I don't think the logs were generated in the first place, so allowing my user to view all the other logs wouldn't have helped anyway.

Comment: `journalctl --user-unit SERVICENAME` works fine even with storage set to volatile. But any of `-u SERVICENAME`, `--user -u SERVICENAME` or `--user --user-unit SERVICENAME` do not work with volatile storage, they all just show "no entries".

Comment: You dont need to restart the box, you can just run `systemctl restart systemd-journald` after making the change to `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. Also the user in question MUST have a uid > 1000 (non system user). if you want to run journalctl commands inside of a different systemd --user unit.

Comment: on systemd 239, you need just `journalctl --user-unit SERVICENAME` without the `--unit` ! And it does not require the user to be in the `systemd-journal` group either.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to make it work with the `--user` and other such options. However, I can see the data when I use `journalctl` on its own. It includes all the logs, though. I can search the specific app I'm interested in and look at that output. To find the latest, I first go at the end of the file then search backward:

1. Hit <kbd>G</kbd> to go to the end (it's a capital `G`)
2. Hit <kbd>?</kbd> and enter your apps name

It's not as practical, but on the device on which I work (a Jetson), that was pretty much the only way I found to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo usermod -a -G systemd-journal $USER
```

or

```
sudo usermod -a -G adm $USER
```

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Users_and_groups#User_groups

Answer (score 0):

you can make a bash script that rans `sudo journalctl` with specific parameter, protect that script from writing, give specific permission to run that script as sudo with no password.
add entry in `/etc/sudoers` as for example

`ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/show_journal.sh`

instead of ALL your can write a specific linux user

Comment: This solution is a workarround, since there is no ACL in the journalctl...

Comment: this is a general solution to customize a specific allowance for accessing system logs, for users who are not root nor `systemd-journal` users (giving inclusive `systemd-journal` access can be risky because `systemd-journal` opens access to sensitive security info)

Answer (score 0):

i had to do this:

```
# mkdir /var/log/journal
# systemd-tmpfiles --create
# journalctl --flush
```

after this, journalctl --user -u SERVICE works for me (RHEL 8.9)

source: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/16141#issuecomment-642628111